# Sharing of static data of a class among threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, static-members

In a multithreaded situation, does every class share the static members of the class? For example, a class has static data members, like the following:

```
class A {
  public:
    static int count;
    ...
};
int A::count(0);
```

Or, the treatment is that every thread gets a separate instance of the static data, or common per process? Ideally, it should be one per process and shared among threads. I have pthreads running in parallel accessing the class static members. Appreciate your opinions, in advance.

Comment: all the object in class share the same static member variable ,I suppose you are using an object per thread, so the variable is shared among threads

Answer (score 2):

```
class A{
public:
        static int a;
        A(int count);
        ~A();
        int inc();
        void print();
};
int A::a = 0;
A::A(int count)
{ a = count; }
A::~A()
{ a = -1; }
int A::inc()
{ a=a+1; }
void A::print()
{ cout<<"value:"<<a<<"\n"; }

void *foo(void *p)
{
        class A *aa = new A(0);
        aa->inc();
        aa->print();
        sleep(5);
        cout<<"foo: ";
        aa->print();
        aa->inc();
        cout<<"foo again: ";
        aa->print();
        delete aa;
}
void *boo(void *p)
{
        class A *bb = new A(10);
        bb->inc();
        sleep(1);
        bb->print();
        sleep(2);
        cout<<"boo: ";
        bb->print();
        delete bb;
}

int main()
{
        pthread_t tid,tid2;
        int ret = pthread_create(&tid,NULL,foo,NULL);
        if(ret < 0)
                cout<<"error1";
        ret = pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,boo,NULL);
        if(ret < 0)
                cout<<"error2";
        pthread_join(tid,NULL);
        pthread_join(tid2,NULL);

return 0;
}
```

**The output for the following is**

```
value:1
value:11
boo: value:11
foo: value:-1
foo again: value:0
```

I think this clarifies, of-course you need to use synchronization for avoiding abnormal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Static member variables are defined once per class and their "accessibility" from other parts of the program is defined in the C++11 standard §11 "Member access control".

Static member variable initialization is performed in a thread safe manner before function `main` will be executed.

However, accessing a variable (class or instance) from different threads where at least one thread modifies the variable requires synchronization primitives like memory barriers, mutex, etc.  Otherwise, your program has "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 0):

The static members are shared between threads in the same process. All the threads will see the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

All threads share common static members of a class .Threads are nothing but executable sequence with a scrap book (stack) within a process .They share memory of the process .And since static members belongs to class they will not be replicated for every instance.